# How to select multiple items in multilistpicker windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I need to display a list of items in list picker,Im using list picker with multiple selection mode.Is there any way to check the check boxes of multiple items from c#(without user's interaction).I found many ways to find the list of selected items but couldnt find how to set multiple items as selected from code behind.Please help.I tried using

```
for(int i=0;i<selecteditems.count;i++)
{
 listpicker.SelectedItem=listpicker.Items[i];
}
```

This doesnt work ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be help you

```
listpicker.SelectedItems = List<your selected items>;
```

Comment: @Jainhind <your selected items> should be the index of the listpicker or the content?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SelectedItems` property for setting multiple items as selected.